# Edit or remove space between Datasets in Stacked Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, charts, bar-chart, stacked

I would like to edit or remove the gaps in a Higharts chart like this:
[image]

Is there any way to style or configure my chart to achieve this?

This is the Demo:
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/codepen/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can control the space between bars using `pointPadding`, `groupPadding` and `borderWidth` properties:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    borderWidth: 0
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/at1r2xLj/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.groupPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.borderWidth